# Cleared straight in approach

Tags: air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules

I was flying IFR (in a simulator with Vatsim ATC) cleared direct to ROXXE on the RNAV 04 at KAVP at 4000 on a course of 275. The controller said "Cross ROXXE at or above 4000, cleared straight in approach RNAV 04". On a course of 275 I expected to enter the procedure turn at ROXXE but instead I was given a clearance that involved a 129 degree turn to the right to line up on final. Would this be a real world clearance in this situation or was the controller shortcutting? If real, how would I be expected to fly this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an incorrect clearance. Per FAA Order 7110.65AA 4-8-1, the intercept angle must be 90 degrees or less for ATC to clear you for a straight-in approach:

> d. Intercept angles greater than 90 degrees may be used when a procedure turn, a hold-in-lieu of procedure
> turn pattern, or arrival holding is depicted and the pilot will execute the procedure.
>
> e. If a procedure turn, hold-in-lieu of procedure turn, or arrival holding pattern is depicted and the angle of
> intercept is 90 degrees or less, the aircraft must be instructed to conduct a straight-in approach if ATC does not
> want the pilot to execute a procedure turn or hold-in-lieu of procedure turn. (See FIG 4−8−3)

ATC can make mistakes. If they clear you do something you don't think is safe and legal, reject the clearance and request an amended one. "Unable straight-in, request full approach" or similar would get the job done.